# Why is my Bevel lopsided?

Tags: bevel

When I bevel this edge the bevel heads up to the right, instead of heading straight up the Z axis.  What am I missing here?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Project file:
[lopsided_bevel.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jyp1odne944mek/lopsided_bevel.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on *Face Orientation* in *Overlays*, you will see that some of your faces are pointing in different directions. Recalculate your Normals to fix it:

[image: RecalcNorm]

Comment: Ha, I feel dumb now. The way that geometry was created I can't imagine why the normal flipped on me.  Gotta remember to look for that.  Thanks so much for looking at my project.